# define an independent static member functrion from class template type

Tags: c++, class, templates

I have created a new class using template,

```
template <class map_t>
class SGridMap {
public:
...
static void save_parameters();
private:
...
}
```

I have two questions :

1. Now there is a static function I want to add (save_parameters) to my class but it doesn't depend at all to the template type class, I don't know if I can do that and how ?
   so I can call the function like this : `SGridMap::save_parameters();` <= which is more intuitive than `SGridMap<some_type>::save_parameters();`
2. can I implement a specific function two different ways, if the template type is int (first implementation) if its char (second implementation), How ?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Interesting question.  Thinking about it at the object-code level, `save_parameters()` needs to know where in memory to find the class's `static` data members, which means that it actually does depend on the template parameter, even though it does not seem to do so.
2. @RakibulHasan is correct.  You can use template specialization, as he has said.